# Gauge Automated Framework Properties Get Malformed

Tags: c#, automated-tests, environment-variables, getgauge

I have also reported this in the following link:

https://github.com/getgauge/gauge/issues/1122

After several cmd executions in parallel, (not the parallel command but executing like 10 cmd lines at the same time) I find the gauge.properties file malformed. It happens sometimes but I have to fix it manually whenever it happens.

Is there a way to make the c# plugin to stop writing the gauge.properties file?
as far as I know, it should only read it.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a workaround, but it works so far. we made the gauge.properties a read only file. This avoids any reading and thus malformation of the file.